# Puppet heredoc with double-quotes in different lines

Tags: puppet

I would like to pass a multi-line command into a Puppet (4.10.12) `exec` resource. The following fails with "syntax error at 'sudo'":

```
exec { 'create databases':
  command => $("EOT")
    sudo -u postgres psql -c
    "CREATE DATABASE db1 ENCODING 'utf8' LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8';
    CREATE DATABASE db2 ENCODING 'utf8' LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8';
    CREATE DATABASE db3 ENCODING 'utf8' LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8'"
    |-EOT,
}
```

I assume what is challenging about this case is that the two double-quotes appear on different lines. So what is the right [heredoc](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/lang_data_string.html#heredocs) syntax for a case like this?

Comment: I would recommend placing the command inside a file within the module `files` directory and then making use of the `file` function (https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#file) to return a string as the value for the `command` attribute. You would then remove the issues with formatting. Does that sound feasible to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following now works:

```
exec { 'create databases':
  command => @("EOT"/L)
    sudo -u postgres psql \
    -c "CREATE DATABASE db1 ENCODING 'utf8' LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8'" \
    -c "CREATE DATABASE db2 ENCODING 'utf8' LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8'" \
    -c "CREATE DATABASE db3 ENCODING 'utf8' LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8'"
    |-EOT
}
```

The following changes were necessary:

- use `@' instead of '$' to refer to heredoc (typo)
- use three `-c` options instead of one (in order to avoid error `CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string`)
- use [heredoc switch](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/lang_data_string.html#enabling-escape-sequences) `L` (as suggested by @mardotio)

I'll accept the other answer since it contains an important element (and is by a new contributor :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add the `L` switch to your heredoc, and add a `\` to the end of each line to escape the new line.

```
$command = $("EOT"/L)
  sudo -u postgres psql -c\
  "CREATE DATABASE db1 ENCODING 'utf8' LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8';\
  CREATE DATABASE db2 ENCODING 'utf8' LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8';\
  CREATE DATABASE db3 ENCODING 'utf8' LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8'"
  |-EOT

exec { 'create databases':
  command => $command,
}
```

You can view documentation [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/lang_data_string.html#formatting-control) under "suppressing literal line breaks".